# The controller for URI "/v1/order/test" is not callable: Invalid service account: Syntax error

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine

I have downloaded a Symfony project from bitbucket and run it locally with docker. Everything is good, but some API is not working and gives the error:

> The controller for URI "/v1/order/test" is not callable: Invalid service account: Syntax error

What is it possible to be?

I mention that code is working fine on dev server but on local gives that. Can anyone give help to me?

I am using symfony 6.0.
This is test code in controller:

```
/**
 * Create and fetch order.
 * @Route("v1/order/")
 */
class OrderController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * @Route("test", name="test", methods={"GET"})
     * **/ 
    public function test(){
        dd("test");
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: what can i do ?